# How to reference MS Word table of contents page numbers with Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to use the page numbers to the right-hand side of a table of contents object in Word in some VBA code. I can access the array storing the text associated with these page numbers using `GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)` but cannot seem to get at the page numbers themselves. None of the GetCrossReferenceItems constants listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172208(v=office.11).aspx) seem relevant.

[image]

Is there a way to reference these page numbers? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a "Worder" so here is what I came up to:

```
Function GetPagesNumber(doc As Document) As Long()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim myHeadings As Variant

    With doc
        Set myRng = .Content
        myRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

        myHeadings = .GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)
        ReDim pages(1 To UBound(myHeadings)) As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(myHeadings)
            myRng.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:=wdRefTypeHeading, ReferenceKind:=wdPageNumber, ReferenceItem:=i
            With .Paragraphs(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.count).Range
                myRng.SetRange Start:=.Start, End:=.End - 1
            End With
            pages(i) = CLng(myRng.Text)
        Next i
    End With
    myRng.Delete
    GetPagesNumber = pages
End Function
```

to be used like follows:

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()
    Dim myPagesNumber() As Long

    myPagesNumber = GetPagesNumber(ActiveDocument) '<-- store index pages numbers in myPagesNumber 
End Sub
```

Comment: @superfluous, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

*Instead of using;*

```
myHeadings = .GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)
```

*You can also use;*

```
Dim myField As Field
Set myField = ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Range.Fields(1)
myHeadings = Split(myField.Result.Text, Chr(13))
```

This will return an array of strings, with within the last characters of the array **the page number** of the heading. Use `pgnr = CInt(Right(myHeadings (i), Len(myHeadings (i)) - InStrRev(myHeadings (i), Chr(9))))` to get the pagenumber.

What would be better is to first split `myHeadings` into rows with `Chr(13)` as delimiter **and** then split into columns with `Chr(9)` as delimiter.

*So the whole table of contents in an array.*